# THTTPRIO - IOHandler value is not valid

Tags: delphi, windows-7, indy, wininet

Using Win7 Pro.

I have a SOAP application created in Delphi 7 that uses THTTPRIO. It has been working fine with HTTP but now they want to use HTTPS.

In most cases it is working fine by just changing the URL to HTTPS and setting the appropriate SSL/TLS settings in Windows Internet Options.

However some systems are getting an "IOHandler value is not valid" error.

It is compiled using the default THTTPRIO settings (no defines) in D7 (to use Wininet not Indy), however that LOOKS like an INDY error.

I've looked through all the links I can find and do not see a solution.

I'm guessing it is either a Windows settings problem or maybe missing / bad Wininet installation? Missing an KB update (or maybe had an update)?

Anyone have any ideas why this error is occurring on some systems but not others of the same OS (Win7 Pro)?

As it looks like an Indy error, I'm also wondering if it somehow got compiled to use Indy (but it seems to respond to the Internet Options settings).
Is there any way to determine if it is using Indy instead?

Comment: "IOHandler value is not valid" is indeed an Indy error message.  It is raised by Indy's `TIdHTTP` component when its `IOHandler` property is not referring to a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived class, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, thus preventing `TIdHTTP` from handling HTTPS urls.  Changing Windows Internet Options affects only WinInet, not Indy.  So clearly, your `THTTPRIO` is using Indy and not WinInet when the error occurs.

Comment: But changing the Windows Internet Options (unchecking all of the SSL/TLS options) makes the RIO not work. returns a "An error occurred in secure channel support" message. That's what's confusing about it.

Comment: If you get the IOHandler error, you are using Indy. If Internet Options affects your app, you are using WinInet.  It is an either-or scenario in HTTPRIO, you can't have it both ways.

Comment: Ok - more digging to do then. Is there an article you can point me to on how to use SSL with the RIO when using INDY?

Comment: No.  But HTTPRIO in D2006 onward handles SSL with Indy for you. But for D7, HTTPRIO did not support SSL with Indy, but you could try backporting [this patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/borland.public.delphi.webservices.soap/puXzN9zwBvg/V2tFRFL-zakJ) to D7 and see if it works.

Comment: I am actually doing this in a DLL (I should have stated that earlier) so I guess I can recompile with XE8 or 10.2.